# Disable cache for certain resource programmatically

Tags: google-chrome, http, browser, fetch, browser-cache

I have this setting in Chrome devtools:

[image]

this setting works for me. However, I also want to disable the cache for certain resources. My question is - is there a way to disable the cache for a resource when you use fetch?

```
fetch(url).then(v => {});
```

is there some option or header that we can use to prevent the browser from using the cache to retrieve the resource?

Comment: specifically looking to disable cache when the url domain is localhost

Comment: as described in the question - it seems like using the checkbox to disable caching will work - but I am looking for a programmatic solution - and only to disable certain resources not all resources if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has the answers I was looking for:

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/03/referrer-and-cache-control-apis-for-fetch/

first make sure caching is disabled on the server, if necessary.

Then in the browser, we can use one of these:

```
fetch(url, {cache: 'no-store'})
```

or

```
fetch(url, {cache: 'no-cache'})
```

and get the result we want to achieve.